# How to change font color for updated Access data in Outlook mail

Tags: vba, email, ms-access, colors, outlook

In  Access 2010 I have tables, e.g. Employee(Pracownicy). I can update the data in the table using the subform and the update button.

Updating the data in the subform automatically generates an Outlook mail containing the data in the updated record.

**I need to change font color for updated data in the mail body.**

[image]

The code to update the data and generate e-mail:

```
Private Sub cmdUpdate2_Click()

CurrentDb.Execute "update Pracownicy" & _
    " SET Identyfikator='" & Me.txtID & "'" & _
    ", Imie='" & Me.txtImie & "'" & _
    ", Nazwisko ='" & Me.txtNazwisko & "'" & _
    ", Wiek ='" & Me.txtWiek & "'" & _
    ", Data_urodzenia ='" & Me.txtData & "'" & _
    ", Miejsce_urodzenia ='" & Me.txtMiejsce & "'" & _
    ", Miejscowosc ='" & Me.txtMiejscowosc & "'" & _
    ", Plec ='" & Me.txtPlec & "'" & _
    " where Identyfikator='" & Me.txtID & "'"

'------------------------------------SEND EMAIL----------------------
'Dim varName As Variant
'Dim strUCC As String
Dim varSubject As Variant
Dim varBody As Variant
Dim Poczta As Object
Dim MojMail As Object

On Error Resume Next 

'varName = ""
varSubject = "Employer List "
varBody = "Hello" & _
    "<br><br>Employer List: " & _
    "<br><br><B>Identyfikator:</B>   " & Me.txtID & "  " & _
    "<br><B>Imie:</B>  " & Me.txtImie & "  " & _
    "<br><B>Nazwisko:</B>   " & Me.txtNazwisko & "  " & _
    "<br><B>Wiek:</B>   " & Me.txtWiek & "  " & _
    "<br><B>Data urodzenia:</B>   " & Me.txtData & "  " & _
    "<br><B>Miejsce urodzenia:</B>   " & Me.txtMiejsce & "  " & _
    "<br><B>Miejscowosc:</B>   " & Me.txtMiejscowosc & "  " & _
    "<br><B>Plec:</B>   " & Me.txtPlec & "  "

Set Poczta = CreateObject("outlook.application")
Set MojMail = Poczta.createitem(0)

With MojMail
    '.To =
    '.BCC =
    .subject = varSubject
    '.ReadReceiptRequested = True
    '.originatorDeliveryReportRequested = True
    .htmlbody = varBody & "<br>"
    .display
    '.send
End With

Set Poczta = Nothing
Set MojMail = Nothing

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox ("Atention")
End If

On Error GoTo 0 
'------------------------------------------------------------------------

DoCmd.Close

MsgBox ("End Update")

End Sub
```

Comment: Note that if you need to send the Access database file to a reader, then the question is off-topic, since it cannot be answered using the details you have presented. It is probably better to word the question without that if you can!

Answer (score 0):

I think this becomes more of an HTML question rather than VBA.  Try adding a FONT tag to the following line and see if that works for you.

```
"<br><br><B><font color="red">Identyfikator:</font></B>   " & Me.txtID & "  " & _
```

Comment: Thank you for your respons, but I am looking for another solution. Changing the font color in the mail is pretty simple as you showed.
I need to automatically change the color of the font but only for the updated positions. Other positions in the mail should be black.

Comment: So add a html font tag to each line with a string variable and set it to whatever color you need based off your criteria.

Comment: I think I can not add it to all items because always in every mail all items will be red. each time in the form MSAccess I will update different position.

Comment: I think I need some condition that will recognize the changed value on the form, and only this value will change to red in the mail.